# Android:host option is not triggered

Tags: android, url, hyperlink, manifest, host

I have the following code in my Manifest file

```
<activity
    android:name="android.gonglu.me.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_malls" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:host="subdomain.domain.com"
            android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

What I want to happen is that on the browser in the device all links to subdomain.domain.com should open a chooser dailog to choose between the browser or the installed app.

This is not happening.

Comment: Which browser? Chrome is notorious for not honoring intents. With other browsers it might be hit or miss.

Comment: Yes its chrome let me try in another one.

Comment: It should work from email -- send yourself an email with the link and confirm that it's working.

Comment: It works :) But only with the per installed stock browser. Still don't know how to enable it on chrome in android.

Comment: I can confirm it works from email as well.

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but you can't "enable it on chrome" -- Chrome simply doesn't honor http intents. If you have control over the website, you could use a custom protocol instead of http.